# DEFAULT_DATABASE in Multi-AZ Environment

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-rds

In the Amazon documentation [Multi-AZ Deployment for MS-SQL Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_SQLServerMultiAZ.html), it mandates not to set default database while creating the user. But the documentation didnt say of any alternatives or countermeasures.
I tried to see what the significance of setting the default DB while creating the login but nothing much came up. So my question is, what are the repercussions if I comply to Amazon documentation and do not set a default DB while creating a login?

Or simply what is the impact of not setting DEFAULT_DATABASE as shown below,

```
ALTER LOGIN [test_dba] SET DEFAULT_DATABASE=[db3]
```

vs.

```
ALTER LOGIN [test_dba]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with setting a default database in a Multi-AZ environment is that the default is not propagated to the standby (mirror) server.  So depending on which server is active when you try to connect, sometimes you will connect to the default and sometimes you won't.  This lack of predictability makes it pointless to associate the default database with the login.  What you need to do is specify the default database using the DATABASE parameter in the connection string when creating a connection to SQL Server.